# SQL Case statement on whether value exists in a different table

Tags: sql, join

I'm a little confused by this query I'm trying to write because it's not a simple left join where null situation. I have an account table, an account_category table (accounts in a category), and a category_request table. category_requests shows what accounts have requested what categories, but account_category shows what accounts are in a given category. So I need to write a query that shows a list of the categories that were requested and whether they are actually enrolled in that category by checking the account_category table. How do I write this?

- `Account` table - id, name
- `Account_category` table - id, account_id, category_id
- `Category_request` table - id, account_id, category_id

I tried something like this but it's not what I'm looking for. I probably need to add a case statement as well.

```
select cr.product, cr.id, ac.id 
from category_request cr
join accounts a on a.account_id = cr.account_id
left join account_category ac on ac.account_id = a.account_id 
                              and cr.id = ac.id
order by cr.account_id;
```

Output columns

```
account_id, category_name, in_category
```

Comment: Please give the DBMS, table structures, data inserts, and what you have already tried as text, (not as images)

Comment: You should improve your question. It's not very readable without any line breaks. You should also include sample data and show us what query you've already attempted.

Comment: Could you add expected result as well ? why are you joining `and cr.id = ac.id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it except InCategory which is missing in your query. Just add this second line to your SELECT

```
select cr.product, cr.id, ac.id
, CASE WHEN ac.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END InCategory
....
```